Where does Kubuntu save its configurations
Where do System Settings in Kubuntu save its configurations?
I want to transfer the settings between accounts and across machines.
Thank you.

Kubuntu isn't unique in its use of KDE Plasma, so why not use the standard documentation (ie. https://github.com/Prayag2/kde_controlcentre?tab=readme-ov-file#readme shows a location I'd look for at first!)   Do note I don't use the kde_controlcentre app so I'm basing this only on generic doco.

Did you mean System Settings? Like most software, System Settings stores its configuration files in ~/.config.

Yes System Settings @UriHerrera. There are so many directories under ~/.config though, KDE do not store its configuration files under a central directory but spreading all over ~/.config?

@xpt That's correct. System Settings is a central hub for the KCMs (KDE Control Modules); there is a System Settings-specific configuration file. However, the KCMs write to separate configuration files in ~/.config. KDE does not use a central directory to store these files for their applications or Plasma.

You should try this widget, worked well for me. It saves the configuration in a tar.gz-file and has otpions to restore settings. Exploring the tar.gz-file will show you all the locations where settings are stored.
